# Multiple substitutions using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

We have a file with million entries as shown below:

```
123,100F,abc
456,250F,xyz
```

Also, we have some mapping as shown below:

```
100F >  522  
150F >  523  
200F >  524  
250F >  525  
300F >  526
```

How can I get the output in required format as shown below:
    second field changed according to mapping and last field with current date.

Output:

```
123,522,2017-01-25
456,525,2017-01-25
...
```

I do not want to hard code like

```
sed "s/100F/522/;s/250F/525/;s/\w*/`$date`" input > output
```

Comment: You can use the `join` command to join two sorted files.  Check out its man page.  Since the third field in your output is constant (current date), this should work.

Comment: The data file contains millions of entries, but how big is the mappings file?

Comment: @Fred: mapping file contains < 20 entries.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" '
    NR==FNR { map[$1]=$3; next }
    { print $1, map[$2], date }
' map FS=, OFS=, file
123,522,2017-01-23
456,525,2017-01-23
```

or if you prefer to keep the FS and OFS setting within the script:

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" '
    NR==FNR { map[$1]=$3; next }
    FNR==1 { FS=OFS=","; $0=$0 }
    { print $1, map[$2], date }
' map file
123,522,2017-01-23
456,525,2017-01-23
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton: it really works. Could you please explain the logic.

Comment: this type of operation is really fast in awk i think

Comment: @user2610 I think it's pretty self-explanatory - is there any part of it you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `awk`, if the mapping file isn't considerable this is stored in a dictionary, then the large file is processed (This can be improved if both files are sorted),

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" '
    BEGIN{FS=",|[ ]+[>][ ]+"; OFS=","}
    FNR==NR{d[$1]=$2; next}
    {print $1,d[$2],date}
' mapping file_with_million
```

or

```
awk -v date="2017-01-25" '
    BEGIN{FS=",|[ ]+[>][ ]+"; OFS=","}
    FNR==NR{d[$1]=$2; next}
    {print $1,d[$2],date}
' mapping file_with_million
```

you get,

```
123,522,2017-01-25
456,525,2017-01-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only "date" as an external reference.  Please note that performance would probably be impacted by my putting the date assignment inside the loop (it can be put outside the loop if you do not care using the current date as of launching the script).

```
#!/bin/bash

mappings_file="mapping"
data_file="data"

# Create a mapping array
declare -A mappings
while IFS= read -r line
do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*\>[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*$ ]] || continue
  key="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  mappings["$key"]="$value"
done <"$mappings_file"

# Perform replacement
while IFS= read -r line
do
  # The regex below requires that there be no extra spacing in the data file ;
  # it could be adjusted to allow it, using the same technique as above
  [[ "$line" =~ ^(.*),(.*),.*$ ]] || continue
  # If you trust that the date will not change during execution,
  # you could put the next assignment outside of the loop
  date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
  key="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  value="${mappings[$key]}"
  # If you need to handle missing mappings, do it here before printing
  printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},$value,$date"
done <"$data_file"
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons not to do that.

Comment: I understand that Bash may not be the best way to handle any specific need (I am not saying my solution is the right one here).  If you think my code is "wrong" (i.e. buggy), please point it out.  Everything is a matter of engineering compromises: sometimes minimizing external dependencies (for performance, portability or simply familiarity of syntax) will trump other considerations.  One other thing a solution based on Bash provides is ability to have variables modified inside the loop, and in some cases this is needed.  Knowing how process text in Bash can be worthwhile in many cases.

Comment: @EdMorton "Why post an answer if you don't think it's the right answer to the question?" : because I do not know the exact situation the OP is in.  Please note I am not saying my proposal is certainly not the right one either.  It is good knowing a few approaches, and being able to contrast the advantages of one or the other in each specific scenario.